# Not understanding a group theory exercise

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Here's the exercise:

> Let $G$ be a group and $x,y \in G\setminus \{1\}$. Let $R$ be any rectangle in the body of the multiplication table of $G$ having $1$ as one of its vertices, $x$ a vertex in the same row as $1$, and $y$ as a vertex in the same column as $1$. Prove that the fourth vertex of $R$ depends only on $x$ and $y$ and not on the position of $1$.

I don't understand what I'm asked to do. What do they mean by "depends on $x$ and $y$"? What kind of dependence are they (probably) talking about? Same thing for $1$; what do they mean by saying that the fourth vertex doesn't depend on the position of $1$?

Comment: This is indeed a weirdly formulated exercise. I suppose by multiplication table it means a matrix $(g_ig_j)_{i,j=1}^{n}$ for some enumeration $g_1,g_2,\ldots,g_n$ of the elements of the (presumably finite) group $G$. I think it asks you to prove that if for some indices $i,j,k,l$ one has $g_ig_j=1$, $g_ig_l=x$, $g_kg_j=y$ then $g_kg_l$ is some expression that depends on $x,y$ only.

Comment: What an awesome exercise.

Comment: @MattSamuel since you think it's awesome, how about this: prove that if a monad has this property and the property that each row and column in the multiplication table contains every element of the monad, then this monad is a group.

Comment: @MattSamuel I gave it a lot of thought, but eventually just surrendered. If you happen to solve it, please let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When they say "depends on $x$ and $y$", you're meant to show that the value of the fourth vertex is a function of $x$ and $y$. In general, there are a lot of $1$'s on the multiplication table, and the goal is to show that, if the rectangle has the aforementioned properties, then the value of the fourth vertex does not depend on which $1$ you pick, or which $x$ and $y$ you pick in the multiplication table. In other words, it shouldn't matter how you pick the vertices of the rectangle, just on the values of $x$ and $y$.

Indeed, suppose the vertices are $(a,b), (c,b), (a,d), (c,d)$, such that $ab=1, ad=x, cb=y$. Then $cd = c\cdot 1\cdot d = c\cdot (ba)\cdot d = (cb)(ad) = yx$, which only depends on $x$ and $y$, and not on how the vertices are chosen.

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand what's meant by the non-dependence on the position of $1$.

Comment: For example, let the group if question by $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $x=4,y=5$. In one case, let the "$1$" vertex be $(1,1)$, and let the other three vertices be $(1,4)$, $(5,1)$, and the last one must be $(5,4)$, which is associated with the value $20$. In another case, let the vertex associated with $1$ be $(2,1/2)$, and let the other vertices be $(2,2)$, $(10,1/2)$, and (consequently) $(10,2)$. Again, the 4th vertex is associated with $20$, even though we had a different choice of the vertex associated with $1$.

Comment: So the question is **equivalent** to the following? "Show that if we pick a $1$ in the body of the multiplication table, then for any chosen $x, y \neq 1$ such that $x$ lies on the same row as $1$ and $y$ on the same column as $1$, the fourth vertex is a function of $x$ and $y$".

Comment: Yes, essentially.

Comment: @OpenBall and florence: No that's the wrong way around! The correct way to state it is: Given any $x,y \in G$, there exists a $z \in G$ such that, if you pick a rectangle in the multiplication table for $G$ with $x,y$ at two opposite corners and $1$ at a third corner, then $z$ is at the last corner. In terms of game semantics, by claiming this you assert that you have a winning strategy for the game where I first pick $x,y \in G$ and then you pick $z \in G$ and then I pick a rectangle in the table with $x,y$ at two opposite corners and $1$ at a third corner and you win if $z$ is at the fourth.

Comment: @OpenBall: So what "$z$ depends on $x,y$ but not on the position of the $1$" means is: You (the claimer) can pick $z$ **before** I (the doubter) pick the position of the $1$, but you have to pick $z$ **after** I pick $x,y$ in the sense that you may need to pick different $z$ for different $x,y$.

Comment: @OpenBall: Your version in the above comment is instead: You have a winning strategy for the game where I first pick $x,y \in G$ and a $1$ in the table and then you pick a $z \in G$ and then I pick a rectangle of the above-described type and you win if $z$ is at the fourth corner. This version is much weaker, because actually once you pick $x,y$ and the position of the $1$ there is only one possible rectangle for me to pick, so trivially you can pick $z$. In contrast, the correct game has $z$ picked **before** the position of the $1$, and there is more than one $1$ so the claim is not trivial.

Comment: @OpenBall: By the way I was careless in my above comment and didn't specify the row/column of the $1$ in the rectangle; that specification is crucial for it to work in a non-commutative group. Can't edit it so...

Answer (score 7):

The statement can be reformulated as follows

> Let $G$ be a group, with $a,b\in G$;
>
> - suppose $ab=1$
> - consider $d$ so that $ad=x$
> - consider $c$ so that $cb=y$
>
> Compute $cd$

Comment: @OpenBall Yes, I switched the symbols in the bulleted list and forgot to change them also at the end.

Comment: @OpenBall As others commented, it's indeed not at all clear. Possibly they meant that if you permute the elements of the group, you get a differently looking table and the rectangle so built is different, but the fourth vertex will always contain the same element.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's *possible* that when you do this, you find out that the last entry in the rectangle is always equal to $x^2$. That "depends only on $x$ and $y$." I think a better way to express this would be "Can expressed in terms of only $x, y, 1,$ and the group operations".

There's also the problem that "1" appears in every row and column of the multiplication table, so saying "$x$ a vertex in the same row as $1$"

doesn't constrain $x$ at all. What's almost certainly meant is this:

> Let $R$ be any rectangle in the body of the multiplication table of
>   $G$--- which we represent as an array $A = (a_{ij})$ with entries in
>   $G$--- having $1$ as one of its vertices, say $a_{pq}$, and $x$ as
>   another entry in row $p$, $y$ another entry in columnn $q$, and $z$ as
>   the fourth corner of the rectangle. Express $z$ in terms of $x, y, 1$
>   and the group operations.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are various possibilities:

```
1 . . . . x     x . . . . 1
. . . . . .     . . . . . .
y . . . . z     z . . . . y
```

etc. I think the question is just asking you to show that $z$ has the same value in all cases.